# Algorithm: Factorialize a Number Douts

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, methods

**I'm doing the factorialize algorithm challenge on FCC and I would really appreciate if someone with a greater knowledge than me would explain me what's wrong in the thinking process of my code**

Im following these steps to factorialize a number:

1. Create a function with a parameter (num).
2. I create an if statement to accomplish the next task: factorialize(0) should return 1. **If (num === 0) {return 1;}**
3. Create an array inside the function.
4. Create a loop to iterate through num-1 numbers and push them into the array. So we add the current number + all the previous values to the array. Example: If our number is 5 we add 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.
5. Use the reduce method into the array to multiply the values of each number in the array (factorialize).
6. Return the given value.

**My code:**

```
    function factorialize(num) {

      if (num === 0) { return 1; }

      else {var array = [];

          for(i = num; i >= 1; i--){
              var newArray = array.push[i];
              newArray.reduce(function(previousVal, currentVal){
              return previousVal * currentVal;
              });
          }
      }
    }

    factorialize(5);
```

**I am mainly getting 2 douts now. This way to solve the algorithm might not be the most efficient one okay but:**

1. Is this a viable way to solve it?
2. Why am I getting "cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined".

**Link to the challenge:**
https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/factorialize-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try this:

```
  function factorialize(num) {

      if (num === 0) { return 1; }

      else {
        for (var i = num - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
          num *= i;
        }
          return num;
      }
    }

factorialize(5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciat your answer. You are right, there is no need to create an array to iterate and operate through numbers. A loop is enough.